# How to Parse only some selected Json arrays and Json Objects from a Url to android device

Tags: android, json, restful-url

I have a Json data and which contains multiple JSON arrays and JSON Objects so i want to parse some of them in an android activity ,...

Example of JSON array and Json objects at [here](http://javatechig.com/api/get_category_posts/?dev=1&slug=android)

So i want to call some of them in the android device....
i know how to parse but i want only some of contents ,..

I have the data like

```
 {
   "process":"done"
    "one":1
   "List": {
    "Something": [
        {
            "Name": "John",
            "phone": "test"
        }
    ]
     "details":"ok"
     "two":2 
    "SomethingElse": [
        {
            "Name": "Smith",
            "phone": "test"
        }
    ]
   }
  }
```

Like that i have a Restful service and it has lot of data ,.. so if want to call "list" or "SomethingElse" jsonObjecs/arrays.... its not calling its strucking at starting,..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider parsing your data the SAX way, just go through your nodes, if it's what you need parse it, otherwise skip it and go on. Have a look [here](http://tech.xtremelabs.com/parsing-json-data-efficiently-on-android-jsonreader/), JSONReader is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer sir,... But by Restful service is not designed from xml,.. Its designed for JSON objects and Json arrays,... SO i want to call them thats it,.. but i want that i need to call any JSON Array or Any JSON object,.. for a Url,,, and that needs to be parsed,.. and in wihch Images are also there Thank you,..

Comment: I was pointing to JSON as well, maybe I used the wrong terminology when I said "nodes". Have a look at the example and the JSONReader class.

Comment: k sir,... is it from a URL,..if so please provide some more links,... or example for that in android,..

Comment: Just to make sure I get the problem right, your json data gets retrieved based on a url request, right? This means you'll get a response with a stream containing your json data. It's that stream that you'll be able to easily parse with JSONReader; If I got it wrong then give me the details to correctly understand your problem.

Comment: yes sir,. its from a Restful service,... and i am parsing that data to  android ,.. so i used this link,.. http://developer-android-tutorial.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-how-to-parse-json-and-show.html  to get the data from url so he used worldpopulation ,.. if i use list or somthing at a that place its getting error,... Please help me sir,..

Comment: PM me with your logcat traces and pieces of code, I'll try to have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Json Array for your above response will be like this

```
     JSONObject JObject = new JSONObject(response);
      String Process = JObject.getstring("process");
    String one= JObject.getstring("one");
    JSONObject Listobject= JObject.getjsonobject("List");
    JsonArray something =Listobject.getjsonarray("Something");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < something.length(); i++){
     JsonObject somethingobject =something.getjsonobject(i);
         String name=somethingobject.getstring("Name"); 
        String phone=somethingobject.getstring("phone"); 
    }

      String details= JObject.getstring("details");
    String two= JObject.getstring("two");

    JsonArray SomethingElse=JObject.getjsonarray("SomethingElse");

    for(int j = 0 ; j < SomethingElse.length(); j++){
     JsonObject SomethingElseobject =SomethingElse.getjsonobject(j);
         String name1=SomethingElseobject .getstring("Name"); 
        String phone1=SomethingElseobject .getstring("phone"); 
    }
```

Code for getting data from server

```
public void run() {

        Log.i("run method", "calling run method");
        try {
            if (method == HttpMethodType.GET) {
                response(executeHttpGet());
            } else {
                response(executeHttpPost());
            }
        } catch (ConnectTimeoutException ex) {
            exception("Please retry after sometime...");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            exception("Server might be down...");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            exception("Please check your internet connectivity...");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            exception(e.getMessage());
        }

        Log.i(tag, "Http Call Finish");
    }

    private void response(String response) {

        if (resListener != null) {
            resListener.handleResponse(response);
        }
    }

    private void exception(String exception) {
        if (excepListener != null) {
            excepListener.handleException(exception);
        }
    }

    public String executeHttpGet() throws Exception {
        Log.i("calling method", "calling execute");
        Log.i("path in method", path);
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String page = null;
        try {

            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(path);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request,localContext);

            Log.i("======", response.toString());
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
                    .getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.i("the response is ::", line);
                sb.append(line);

            }
            in.close();
            page = sb.toString();
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return page;
    }
```

Comment: hellow Ravneet sir,... i need to call this from a Restful service i mean from a URL once check this link http://developer-android-tutorial.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-how-to-parse-json-and-show.html i how i need to access the above data if its coming from a url