# How to parse Multiple JSON Objects and arrays from a url in android? i am using a example i want it in that example,

Tags: android, json, restful-url

I want below process on with out editing on server side

I followed [this](http://developer-android-tutorial.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-how-to-parse-json-and-show.html) example

but over there he is calling data with one json object from a [url](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/jsonparsetutorial.txt)

called "worldpopulation",..

but i have a Json data which is having lot of Json  objects and arrays,.. like below code

```
{ "getting data":"ok"
   "Todays":population
   {"results"{[
   "worldpopulation": 
[
     {
     "rank":1,"country":"China",
     "population":"1,354,040,000",
     "flag":["http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/china.png"]
     }, 
{
    "population":{
     [
    "countrypulation"        {
     "rank":2,"country":"India",
     "population":"1,210,193,422",
     "flag":["http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/india.png"]
     },
```

like that i have a lot of data i want this data in that above example. Without changing any thing on server side,.. or Restful service,..
thank you

Comment: refer to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20492940/how-to-parse-only-some-selected-json-arrays-and-json-objects-from-a-url-to-andro/20493527#20493527

Comment: hellow ravneet sir yesterday its not worked for me,... please do this how it work on above example and mail me,.. please sir...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

response

```
JSONObject JObject = new JSONObject(response);
      String getting_data = JObject.getstring("getting data");
    String Todays= JObject.getstring("Todays");
    JsonArray results =JObject.getjsonarray("results");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < results.length(); i++){
     JsonObject resultsobject =results.getjsonobject(i);

    JsonArray worldpopulation 
=resultsobject.getjsonarray("worldpopulation");
         for(int j = 0 ; j < worldpopulation.length(); j++){
     JsonObject worldpopulationobject =worldpopulation.getjsonobject(j);
     JsonObject emptyobject =worldpopulationobject.getjsonobject("");
         String rank=emptyobject .getstring("rank"); 
        String population=emptyobject .getstring("population"); 
        JsonArray flagarray =countrypulation.getjsonarray(flag);
        for(int n = 0 ; n < flagarray.length(); n++){
        JsonObject flagarrayobject =flag1array.getjsonobject(n);
        String flag=flag1arrayobject .getstring("flag"); 
        }

     JsonObject populationobject 
=worldpopulationobject.getjsonobject("population");
         JsonArray emptyarray =JObject.getjsonarray("");
    for(int k = 0 ; k < emptyarray.length(); k++){
        JsonObject emptyarrayobject =emptyarray.getjsonobject(k);
        JsonObject 
countrypulation=emptyarrayobject.getjsonobject("countrypulation");

         String rank1=countrypulation .getstring("rank"); 
        String country=countrypulation .getstring("country"); 
        String population1=countrypulation .getstring("population");
        JsonArray flag1array =countrypulation.getjsonarray(flag);
        for(int m = 0 ; m < flag1array.length(); m++){
        JsonObject flag1arrayobject =flag1array.getjsonobject(m);
        String flag1=flag1arrayobject .getstring("flag"); 
        }
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: hellow ravneeth sir i am not using this like in my server... JSONObject JObject = new JSONObject(response);

Comment: @user2967727 well, response is a string here, in which all the response coming from server is put. He assumes that you have all of that response in string named "response" and then he parse that.

Comment: Yes that is how i did.

Answer (score 1):

You parse

```
{
    ...
}
```

as JSONObject and

```
[
    ...
]
```

as JSONArray. JSONArray contains your objects. From the JSONObject you can retrieve the property values.

```
JSONArray response = new JSONArray('your json string');

for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
    response.getJSONObject(i).getString("property"));
}
```

BTW your json is invalid, event if you close the missing brackets. Check it here http://jsonlint.com/