# How to implement a multi level tree view from dynamic response?

Tags: android, dynamic, treeview, multi-level

Here i am posting my url.the url contains dynamic responses.so please suggest me to implement a multi level treeview in android using below url format.

http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bVikVZXbzC?indent=2

Answer (score 0):

check the library at [TreeView](https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView)

- Its N-level tree.
- Custom style for nodes
- Save state after rotation

[image]

Comment: Ramanjeet i tried this library too.but i dont have an idea to create the dynamic tree nodes.do you have any idea to parse the above url and create it.

Comment: @sundarraj your provided link can be easily parsed using JSON objects and arrays.check ref. link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20513370/how-to-parse-multiple-json-objects-and-arrays-from-a-url-in-android-i-am-using

Comment: i know to parse if its a static but its a dynamic url.the array might have lots of inner arrays.my question is how to create the tree nodes and childs for every arrays.i just want to make an array title as nodes and array values are childs.we dont sure about structure it will change at any time based on the option selection.

Comment: okay, there might be certain libraries for that purpose too, but my preference was to make some public static or maybe final variables class and make changes to those variables according to the dynamic conditions...